# Convert double 15,34 to 15.34

Tags: localization, decimalformat

I'm trying to get a json string but I noticed that when I pass some double numbers to my query the integer part is separated by a coma from the floating part. I need them to be separated by a point. Is this connected to the Language of the os?

Comment: Yes, it is a localisation issue.

Comment: Well, we don't know where your json string comes from.  It has nothing to do with json, and everything to do with the entity sending this to you.  show a [mcve]

Comment: What query, and how are you passing the double? As a double or as a `String`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: I'm passing as a string. I'm retrivieng my postion from Geolocator class and passing the coordinates to a query which uses Apix api to get weather information on my location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex to fix this issue:

`\d+,\d+` to select the offending bits of JSON, and a string-based replace on the results. If you already have the numbers separated out, use the replace function (something like `val.replace(",",".")`) on the value you have, and cast it to a float (`float(val)` in Python).